# calling url of main app to template of other app

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to call a URL from main apps view function into child apps template

This is my directory structure:

```
App/
   Main/
       templates/
                main/
                    index.html
       urls.py
       views.py
   Other/
        templates/
                 other/
                      base.html
        urls.py
        views.py
```

This is my urls.py from main app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('other/', include('other.urls')),
]
```

I am trying to call home page in base.html of other app on navbar like this

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'main.home' %}">Main App</a>
```

I am not calling the link in urls of other app.

This is my view function in main views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

I have tried importing the home function in views of other app and then passing into urls of other app which makes url `localhost:8000/other/home` I want that url to stay as `localhost:8000/` for main page whenever that link is clicked.

Comment: I think you forgot to paste your code under "I am trying to call home page in base.html of other app on navbar like this Main App"? Or what do you mean with "calling the link"?

Comment: I fixed link. It wasn't visible before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I created the base.html file in other app I should have created in main app so Moved the file location after move directory structure became like this

```
App/
   Main/
       templates/
                main/
                    index.html
                    base.html
       urls.py
       views.py
   Other/
        templates/
                 other/
                      #more Templates
        urls.py
        views.py
```

Putting Files in right order was solution.